# Regular expression - Strange behavior

Tags: regex, compiler-construction

I'm writing a compiler. I'm just starting, so I'm creating the Scanner (or Lexer). Currently, I'm writing some regular definitions which will be processed by my scanner. Trying to create one of them, I run in the next problem:

I was testing, in [**RegExr**](http://www.regexr.com/), the following (incredibly simple) regular expression:

```
r = /(a|ab)/
```

Where "r" is a regular definition; I mean, the regular expression just is `(a|ab)`.

I thought the language L(r) would be (according to the book **[Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321493028)**):

```
L(r) = {a, ab}
```

Surprisingly, the tool matches `{a}`!

So my question is, **why this behavior?**

Comment: `|` in regex is an alternator, ie your regex will match either `a` _or_ `ab`.  Do you want it to match `a` _followed by_ `ab`?

Comment: Hi @JamesThorpe, actually I don't want to "find" a regular expression. What I'm looking for is understand the above strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `a|ab` matches "a" or "ab" (obviously), but some tools/languages (eg Java) consider the input to match when the *entire* input matches the regex, while others (eg JavaScript) consider input to match when *some* of the input matches.

Your tool must be a "some" variety to match "{a}".

Comment: Do you know an online tool which behaves like Java regex tools?

Comment: @LeonardoManrique no, but you can make it behave so by adding `^` to the front and `$` to the end, eg `^a|ab$`. btw your regex is equivalent to `ab?`

Comment: Do you refer to a lexem? If so, I don't want to match a lexem with a pattern, I was just designing regular definitions. When I tried to use that tool, I ran with the "error" we've been discussing. If you are refering on the regex itself, it's equivalent to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

A regex parses the text from left-to-right and in case of an alternator (`|`) it will first aim to match with the first candidate.

If you use:

```
(ab|a)
```

It will match both `ab` and `a`'s.

The point is that once a match is found, a global matcher will start the next match attempt **after** the end of the first match.

You can easily verify that the matched language is `{a,ab}`: use the regex `^c(a|ab)d` and use `cabd`. In that case, the regex has no choice but selecting the second option.

So say the regex reads: `(a|ab)` and the text is `ab`. It will match with `a`, next it will start after `a`, so it will attempt to match with `b`, but fail.

Most lexer tools however use a different way to determine the match. For lexer tools, the "*longest match*" counts. So the match with the longest number of characters.

Now if you enter `(a|ba)` as regex, it will match earlier `ba` earlier. Why? Because it also aims to find the first attempt. And in the text `cbad`, starting at index `1` (`b`) is seen as better than starting at index `2` (`a`).

Comment: Hi CommuSoft. Yes, you have right, but if I write this regex: (a|ba), the tool matches {a, ba}.

Comment: @LeonardoManrique: well it matches buth. If you would use `^(a|ab)$` and match with `ab` it will match.

Comment: @LeonardoManrique: sorry understood your comment wrong, see modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @bohemian some regex evaluate just a part of the string if you want to match the whole string you can use a regexp like this:

```
/^(a|ab)$/
```

Which only will accept **a** or **ab**